# Merge request sent from local branch to master while pushing some changes to local branch

Tags: git, github, git-commit, merge-request

We have 5 branches Master, INT, QA, PROD-EXT, PROD-INT. 
Some changes were made in the QA server and the changes were pushed to the QA branch. Then Got an email saying "pushed new commits to merge request". We never requested for this to merge to master.

Changes are pushed to local branches everyday but it is strange that we saw merge requests similar to this only a handfull of times. In all cases we never requested to merge.

Commands used to push changes

```
git status
git add changed-file
git commit -m "file-a modified"
git push
```

Answer (score 0):

That kind of message is seen in GitLab Merge Request, as illustrated by [`gitlab-org/gitlab` issue 30879](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/issues/30879)

So check if one of those branches were pushed not just to GitHub, but also on a mirror/clone on GitLab, where an old Merge Request might have been initiated.